# error occur when try to SELECT in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

so i recently learn to write a code in android using sqlite and i try to select data from sqlite but this error occur

ive tried some suggestion from the internet and read my book but i didnt solve my problem

```
public Penyakit getPenyakit1(String namaGejal){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  String query = "SELECT idPen FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + 
  namapen + " =\"" + namaGejal + "\"";
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
  Penyakit penyakit = new Penyakit();
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    penyakit.set_nomber(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getColumnName(0)));
    penyakit.set_namaPen(cursor.getColumnName(1));
    penyakit.set_idPenyakit(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getColumnName(2)));
    penyakit.set_namGej(cursor.getColumnName(3));
    penyakit.set_idGejala(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getColumnName(4)));
    cursor.close();
  } else {
    penyakit=null;
  }
  return penyakit;
}
```

this is logcat

```
Process: com.example.lordbramasta.pakar, PID: 18914
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "idPen"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at  com.example.lordbramasta.pakar.DBAdapter.getPenyakit1(DBAdapter.java:79)
```

i expected the value of idPen get selected , thank you

Comment: does your sql work if you put it directly in your database as a query?

Comment: yes it does, im using Db browser for sqlite @Livo

Comment: which error occurs? you have any log?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley i updated im sorry i forget

Comment: maybe use these `\`\`` around idPen?

Comment: which is line 79?

Comment: idPen is a variable ive tried to change it into "select" + idPen + " from" but it didnt work @Livo

Comment: penyakit.set_nomber(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getColumnName(0))); @PierGiorgioMisley

Comment: wait, idPen is a variable? what kind of variable is it?

Comment: private static final String idPen="idPen"; @PierGiorgioMisley

Comment: ok. go debugging and check what cursor.getColumnName(0) returns (stop debugger at line 79)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
penyakit.set_nomber(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getColumnName(0)));
```

`cursor.getColumnName(0)` returns `idPen` as this is the name of the only column returned by your query:

```
SELECT idPen FROM ....
```

and your code is trying to cast the string `"idPen"` to an integer. 
So [getColumnName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnName(int)) returns the name of the column at a specified index and not the value of the column.
You should do

```
penyakit.set_nomber(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
```

or if the data type of the column `idPen` is `INTEGER` then:

```
penyakit.set_nomber(cursor.getInt(0));
```

Also don't try to get any other columns because your query returns only 1.
*Note*: remove that `cursor.moveToFirst();` inside the if block because it is already executed.

Comment: ive tried you suggestion but new error occur, the erre : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: My suggestion is about the error you mention in your question. If you altered your code and now face another error, post another question with the relevant code and the new error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use a `'` instead of `"`. So, change the query to the following:

```
String query = "SELECT idPen FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + 
namapen + " =\'" + namaGejal + "\'";
```

I'm suggesting you to use [SQLiteDatabase.query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead rawQuery like this:

```
// Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
// you will actually use after this query.
String[] projection = {
    "idPen"
    };

// Filter results WHERE "namapen" = 'namaGejal'
String selection = "namapen" + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { namaGejal };

// How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
String sortOrder = null; // null for default order

Cursor cursor = db.query(
    TABLE_CONTACTS,         // The table to query
    projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
    selection,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
    selectionArgs,          // The values for the WHERE clause
    null,                   // don't group the rows
    null,                   // don't filter by row groups
    sortOrder               // The sort order
    );


  // do something with the cursor
```

Please take a look [Read information from a database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#ReadDbRow)